# Smallest microcontroller?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am looking for a microcontroller that is small (like a attiny10) which is the smallest one I could find.
Requirements I need: analogRead on 1 pin, 7 pins for analogWrite to micro leds so in total 10 pins (ground, power, analogRead, analogWrite). It's circuitry has to be basic no adding extra things like a crystal oscillator etc.. This will allow me to send a certain code to the recieving pin and then the microcontroller decide which led to turn on.

Comment: 10 pins already rules out the smallest microcontrollers. Also I'm sure you have other requirements, like the minimum amount of (flash/ram) memory it has, does it have to be through-hole or surface mount. Since you're posting this on an Arduino site, does it need to be compatible with the Arduino IDE? Does it need to be an AVR processor? There are other ways to control individual LEDs that don't need an output pin per LED. Have you looked into those?

Comment: The physical size of a microcontoller is mainly dictated by its pins. The distance between each pin is set by the package type. The typical hobbyist microcontrollers use the DIP package with 0.1" pin pitch. But when you have chosen a fitting microcontroller, which fits all your requirements, you can choose a different package, which is small enough for you. Though that will be difficult to solder, if you don't have the right tools

Comment: [PSoC 4000](https://www.cypress.com/file/138646/download) are truly small (even tinier than an ATtiny10): about 1.5 x 1.5mm in a WLCSP package (16 "pins"/balls). They're still quite powerful: 32-bit Cortex M0@16MHz with 16KB of flash and 2KB of RAM. They don't have enough PWM outputs though...

Comment: PSOC doesn't match my requirements. I'll study more of the specifics and get back to you. thanks <3

Comment: For LED driving you don't need hardware PWM - software generated PWM is more than adequate. A little bit of jitter really doesn't matter for LEDs.

Comment: So ur saying that you can make 2 leds turn off on etc seperatly with only software and no giant libraries that would fill a attiny10?

Comment: Yes. I once made an electronic candle with an rgb led and a pic10 - only had about 300 bytes of flash and 16 bytes of ram.

Comment: can you tell me how i would do that?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. On the PIC10 I had a tight loop with a counter and three (R, G and B) duty cycle variables. Plus a crude PRNG routine. All written in assembly language. You would probably be fine using a timer or something like that if you want to make it more concurrent.

Comment: check out this EEVBLOG video ... multiple microcontrollers may be the way to go ... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VYhAGnsnO7w

Comment: EEVBLOG helped me find some microcontrollers.

Comment: You can drive 12 LEDs out of 4 digital pins using [Charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing).

Comment: "doesn't match my requirements", "changed my plans" - So only you know what you want to do and can decide what you need to do it. While it is interesting to contemplate, this question is under-specified, seems to be a moving target, and doesn't appear to be about Arduino hardware or software. [Voting put on hold pending OP update].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's really the smallest you can find but... The
[ATtiny84](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny84) has an ADC, more digital pins than you need, and is
available in 3 mm packages (UFBGA and VQFN). There is also an
[Arduino-compatible core](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) available for it.

Comment: The Attiny84 is huge compared to what I need sadly. I need something like the attiny10 but with more pins. preferabily avr

Comment: More pins = more size - unless you want to go BGA or chipscale, which is normally outside the abilities of hobbyists.

Comment: @Macaroni, 3mm x 3mm is huge?

Comment: @Majenko I changed my plans but I still need alot of pins so I might use BGA. I found 2 microcontrollers but I'll have to watch a video to learn about how to solder them because they are WACK. Which one is compantibe with arduino ide and which one should I choose etc.. I need alottt of pins its a big project. Like a mini computer is what im working to.

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/ATMEL-AVR_MICROCHIP_AT91SAM9G45C-CU_AT91SAM9G45C-CU_C111548.html
15 X 15mm 324 pin

https://lcsc.com/product-detail/NXP-MCU_NXP-Semicon-MCIMX6U5EVM10AC_C394782.html
11 X 11mm 624 pin

Comment: JLCpcb seems to have a smt service. Don't know if they would do bga so :/

Comment: You said you needed 10 pins. Is that a "lot"?

Comment: "I changed my plans"

Answer (score 0):

I made a Arduino develop board with [ATtiny3217](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/07/arduino-compatible-development-board-with-attiny3217/), it has a 24-pin VQFN form factor, but as powerful as ATmega328p, with no external crystal and capable running at 20MHz.

If this is not suitable for you, look into the new [tinyAVR family](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/8-bit/avr-mcus/device-selection), they are the new generation of ATtiny with more functionalities than the older ATtiny family with the smaller footprint.